# audio buffer allocation or not?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio

after posting here couple of times regarding memory issues with reading a buffers in iphone, i was told to not malloc anything in the callback function .

so i took it out , and now i dont malloc the buffer, and now the memory is growing in 1mb per second !!

it seems that i dont understand something basic here, and i will be happy to here what will i have to do.

the other answers, were not too specific for me, so i couldnt point what EXACTLY to do .

here is the new callback :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) 
{



    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; //* sizeof(SInt16) ?
    buffer.mData = NULL;// **took out : malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );**

    // Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;


    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 
                              ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                              inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                              &bufferList); 



   int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;
    for(int i=0; i < inNumberFrames; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",q[i]);
    }



    return noErr;



}
```

Comment: Does removing the NSLog make a difference?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?  I don't see how it can work properly as written.